# 'to' parameter not valid error using Mailgun in Phoenix app via Heroku

Tags: phoenix-framework, mailgun, mailer

I'm trying to follow a tut to create an mailer in my phoenix app.  I've got pretty far but now I'm trying to send a test email from the iex console I get the following error:

```
iex(2)> Radios.Mailer.my_first_email("myemail@domain.com")
{:error, 400,
 "{\n  \"message\": \"'to' parameter is not a valid address. please check documentation\"\n}"}
```

*mailer.ex*

```
defmodule Radios.Mailer do
  use Mailgun.Client,
      domain: Application.get_env(:radios, :mailgun_domain),
      key: Application.get_env(:radios, :mailgun_key)

  def my_first_email(email_address) do
                send_email to: "email_address", #<= this appears to be the issue
                from: "test@example.com",
                subject: "My first email",
                text: "This is an email send with Phoenix and Mailgun"
  end
end
```

*config.exs*

```
config :radios,
  ecto_repos: [Radios.Repo],
  mailgun_domain: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/XXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org",
  mailgun_key: "pubkey-XXXXXXXX"
```

I've been messing around changing double quotes to single, and `send_email(to: :email_address)` and have also added my own actual address in there as well.

All with no joy.

What am I missing?

**Update**
Have changed *config.exs* to the below:

```
config :radios,  Radios.Mailer,
  mailgun_domain: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/XXXXXXXX.mailgun.org",
  mailgun_key: "pubkey-XXXXXX"
```

But now receive:

```
iex(1)> Radios.Mailer.my_first_email("myemail@domain.com")
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in IO.chardata_to_string/1
    (elixir) lib/io.ex:445: IO.chardata_to_string(nil)
    (elixir) lib/path.ex:468: Path.join/2
    (elixir) lib/path.ex:450: Path.join/1
             lib/client.ex:44: Mailgun.Client.send_without_attachments/2
```

Comment: Typo? `"email_address"` should be `email_address` since you want to use the value of the variable, not the string `"email_address"`.

Comment: `send_email to: email_address,` issues the same error.

Comment: Exactly the same error? Are you sure?

Comment: Just restarted the server and now get:

`{:error, 401, "Forbidden"}`

That maybe points to my credentials?

Comment: Try `Application.get_env(:radios, Radios.Mailer)[:mailgun_domain]` and `...[:mailgun_key]` instead.

Comment: That works.  But I also swapped from using the public API which Mailgun suggested to the basic API key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes:

1. `email_address` is a variable but you're passing the string `"email_address"` to the `to` argument of `send_email`. This:

   ```
   send_email to: "email_address",
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   send_email to: email_address,
   ```
2. You're fetching the wrong settings from env. The settings are stored in the keyword list `Application.get_env(:radios, Radios.Mailer)`.

   This:

   ```
   use Mailgun.Client,
       domain: Application.get_env(:radios, :mailgun_domain),
       key: Application.get_env(:radios, :mailgun_key)
   ```

   Should be:

   ```
   use Mailgun.Client,
       domain: Application.get_env(:radios, Radios.Mailer)[:mailgun_domain],
       key: Application.get_env(:radios, Radios.Mailer)[:mailgun_key]
   ```